# How could i set the height of a Dojo TitlePane, relative to the size of the outer container node?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

In the next example I created a TitlePane between a 200px height container. I set the TitlePane height at 100%, but it doesn't seems to expands.

Relevant code:

```
var titlePane = new TitlePane({
    title: "TITLE",
    toggleable: false,
    style: "height: 100%; overflow-y: auto",
    content: "foo"
});
var outerPane = new ContentPane({
    content: titlePane,
    style: "height: 200px;"
}, dojo.byId("body2"));
```

Full example:

http://jsfiddle.net/bzFPM/

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workarount using the accordion container. It's look nearly identical when only contains a pane with title.

```
function example(ContentPane, Accordion, Button){

var titlePane = new Accordion({
       style: "height: 100%; overflow-y: auto"
     });

var innerPane = new ContentPane({title:'TITLE', content:'foo'})

titlePane.addChild(innerPane);

var outerPane= new ContentPane({
    content:titlePane,
    style: "height: 200px;"
}, dojo.byId("body2"));

outerPane.startup()
var button= new Button({
    label:"add line",
    onClick:function(ev){
        innerPane.set("content", innerPane.get("content")+"<br>foo")
    }    
}).placeAt(dojo.byId("body2"), "after");
}

require(["dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer",
     "dijit/form/Button"], example );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bzFPM/5/

Answer (score 1):

Add this style

```
.dijitTitlePaneContentOuter 
{
    height:80%;   
}
```

I'm not sure this is the best option or not. But it's also work.

http://jsfiddle.net/bzFPM/4/